# ubuntu not working properly after installation with window

Tags: ubuntu

I installed ubuntu 12.04 along with window 7, window7 working fine but with ubuntu 12.04 have lots of problem as given below :

```
Machine configuration :
Processor : Core2 duo
2. RAM : 4GB
3. Mother Board : Intel
4. Graphic Card : 1 GB NVIDA
5. Hard-Drive : 500 GB

1) When I boot system and select ubuntu12.04 OS, It generate lots of Heat.
2) When I perform any task system 100% CPU and as result system hanged I checked through task monitoring tool.
3) system not run properly and smoothly.
```

> I do lots of research on google regarding this problem and apply many
>   solution but it could not help to fix that problem. Please help what
>   is the problem with machine and hardware..

Comment: From the terminal run the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` and check whether the results offer you a proprietary graphics driver to install for your NVIDIA graphics card. Ubuntu usually runs faster than Windows on the same hardware, and as a result it also runs hotter than Windows. In this regard Ubuntu is a shill for the latest hardware.

Comment: Thanks Karel I would apply changes later. Is that problem due to graphics card ?

Comment: I don't know because some early point releases of Ubuntu 12.04 are vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug, so you should run the Software Updater application to update your software as soon as possible.